# YouTube Data API v3 daily quota only 10 000 vs 1000 000

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api

I have 2 similar google accounts. Both of them i use with "YouTube Data API v3" to automatically upload videos, but:

One of them has daily quota for 1 000 000 and other only 10 000.

Both accounts are fresh and has no credit card attached so why is only 10 000 available on second and how 2 make it 1 000 000?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have checked the API, and the default quota limit is to [10.000 Queries per day](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota). However, accounts that had enabled the YouTube Data API before April 20, 2016, will still have the old quota limit.

To increase this limit above the 10.000 queries per day value, you can apply for a higher quota using this [link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform), and the YouTube API team will consider increasing it for your project.

You can find this limit in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas), under:

> API explorer > YouTube Data API v3 > Quotas

And you can see his link after pressing the edit limit button.

Comment: I have 1 000 000 on all my other accounts..

Comment: Checking [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota), seems that the new default quota is of 10.000 units/day, but projects that had enabled the API before April 20, 2016, still have the old quota limits.

Comment: They will probably be changing all the old quota limits to the new 10,000, this just happened to my old account from 2016.